# ZFS replication between 2 ZFS file systems

Tags: replication, zfs

I initially replicated tank/storage1 --> usb1/storage1-slave (depicted below), and then (deliberately) destroyed the snapshot I replicated from. By doing this, did I lose the ability to incrementally (zfs send -i) replicate between these 2 file systems? What's the best way to approach SYNC'ing these file systems after destroying this snapshot?

```
# zfs list
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank                  128G   100G    23K  /tank
tank/storage1         128G   100G   128G  /tank/storage1
usb1                  122G   563G    24K  /usb1
usb1/storage1-slave   122G   563G   122G  /usb1/storage1-slave
usb1/storage2          21K   563G    21K  /usb1/storage2
```

What if I initially RSYNC'd tank/storage1 --> usb1/storage1-slave, and decided to incrementally replicate 'via zfs send -i'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-i` option to `zfs send` needs at least one snapshot to send 'starting from' (and optionally a second snapshot as the 'ending at' point). If you have no snapshots, then no more `-i`.

You can still sync the two using the send command, it's just going to send the whole thing.